# Is "successfully" redundant in "XYZ successfully crossed 1 mil customer mark"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In the following statement

> XYZ successfully crossed 1 mil customer mark

1. Is ***successfully*** not required?
2. What additional information does ***successfully*** provide about the situation?
3. Can't I just say ***"XYZ crossed 1 mil customer mark"***?

Comment: "Successfully" stresses the fact that it is not very easy to cross the 1 million customers mark. Your question #3 would make this sentence less emphatic w.r.t to the success factor.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy agreed.  I would also add that "successfully" stresses or implies that there is little-to-no ambiguity for whether or not 1 mil customers were achieved.

Comment: To me, the word "successfully" indicates that 1m customers was a *target*. Without it, the sentence could just be reporting that the number of customers had reached an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Successfully adds emphasis, which may add meaning if the action had been tried and failed before, or is tried by many but accomplished by few. It indicates that the action is a good or desirable thing rather than a neutral or negative thing (as in, crossing the 1 mil customer mark from havning previously been at 10 mil).

Comment: A good answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The successfully here is redundant, unless there's some way to cross the one million mark incorrectly (which doesn't sound like the case). This word is typically given for emphasis, not as additional information.

Comment: But there is absolutely no reason why it should not be used here for emphasis, and other reasons which @bmeraz explains.

Comment: In this sentence, "succesfully" is perhaps used because one million was a goal to achieve and this objective was *successfully* fulfilled.

Comment: Yes--emphasis, not information. Despite Twain's "very" quip, emphasis is fine. But let's be clear that's what it is. Is there a way to achieve/fulfill a goal/objective that is not successful?  Redundancy has a place, but it is redundant.

Comment: I just meant that adding "succesfully" suggests that there was an objective to reach. Otherwise, the sentence would just be factual: the reader can't then infer if it's a success or if it's disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

**Successfully** is being used as an adverb. Adverbs are used to modify other adverbs, adjectives, or verbs. In many if not most contexts, adverbs with **-ly** endings are unnecessary but instead provide explanation, emphasis, or style to an otherwise drab sentence. In your case, I believe the latter is the most relevant. Whereas **easily**, **quickly**, or **surprisingly**, for instance, would have different purposes. Redundant? OK. But style is what makes writing so much fun! (And in terms of print ads or company stock portfolios, is a reason people buy your stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is less a linguistics question and more a question of *communication* and *information density*.

I say that usage of *successfully* is not merely superfluous, but improper if  Company XYZ had not -at some point in the past- defined "Crossing the 1 million customer mark" as a Good Thing to be achieved.

Decorating "crossed the 1 mil customer mark" with *successfully* indicates that this was a mark that was specifically targeted.

If this was not the case, then inclusion of "successfully" conveys meaning that is not present, and is therefore improper.